# Problem with image and transparent filter for IE

Tags: css, transparency

I'm coding a simple bands that goes on at the bottom of the browser on my website. I had everything under control using a semi transparent PNG as my background, but for more flexibility I was asked to do it purely in CSS. So I used an background with a RGBa with a fallback to solid color and, using a conditionnal style sheet, the Microsoft filter for IE 8 and earlier. This works fine, my background looks like I want it to be. The problem I have is that this banner contains an image that is taller than it. Since I've added the filter, it now gets crop in IE... If a switch to a solid background, everything works fine.

Is this a known issue? Is there any workaround?

Here's my IE css:

```
/* This is the banner taking the whole browser width */
#bottompub {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;    
    text-align: center;
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B289BAE4,endColorstr=#B289BAE4)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B289BAE4,endColorstr=#B289BAE4);   /* IE6 & 7 */
    zoom: 1;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:visible; /* Just to make sure no parent change that to hidden */
}

/* This is the image in the banner */
#bottompub .pubimage { 
    position:relative;   
    margin-left:220px;
    height:75px;  
}


/* This is to fit my content web site width the image is in there */
#bottompub .insidebottompub {
    width:1031px;   
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;     
}
```

Here is the simple HTML:

```
<div id="bottompub">
    <div class="insidebottompub">                              
        <a href="http://www.mysite.com"><img class="pubimage" src="myimageof75px.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

*Edit to not use negative margin*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a fix for the filter problem, but a workaround that works on IE7 and Firefox without needing conditional stylesheet and getting the same effect. I used a separated div for my backgound color and my content. For some reason, I had to put the background *after* the content, otherwise the transparency was still inherit and the image was cropped. I used the z-index to show elements in the proper order. I kept the main div bottompub mainly to keep thing organized and have a distinct id for all elements in that section.

CSS:

```
#bottompub {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;   
}

#bottompub .background {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#89BAE4; 
    opacity: .80;    
    filter: alpha(opacity="80");
    z-index: 50;
}


#bottompub .insidebottompub {
    position:relative;
    width:1031px;   
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    z-index: 100;    
}

#bottompub .pubimage {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    left:220px;
    top:-25px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="bottompub">
    <div class="insidebottompub">                              
        <a href="http://mysite.com"><img class="pubimage" src="myimage.png"/></a>
    </div>
    <div  class="background"/>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a [known issue](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#filter) - click the link marked *flaws* for some things to try

I tried a bit and can get it to work for IE8, but not 7, here's the code with some notes to show what I tried for IE7 (ignore the colors they were there to help visualise)

CSS:

```
/* This is the banner taking the whole browser width */
#bottompub {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;    
    background: transparent;
    background: #cfc;

    zoom: 1;
    /*-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B289BAE4,endColorstr=#B289BAE4)"; /* IE8 */    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B289BAE4,endColorstr=#B289BAE4);   /* IE6 & 7 */    

}

/* This is the image in the banner */
#bottompub .pubimage { 
    height:75px;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    /*z-index: 1;*/
}


/* This is to fit my content web site width the image is in there */
#bottompub .insidebottompub {
    width:1031px;   
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: #0f0;
    position: relative;
    /*z-index: 1;*/
}

.insidebottompub a {
position: relative; /* important*/
/* applying hasLyout here doesn't work for IE7 */
}

#bottompub {
/* no z-index or IE8 breaks */
/*z-index: -1;*/
}
```

applying `position: relative;` to the link holding the image seemed to be the main thing but there are other changes

Comment: You're  right, your solution does work fow IE8; not for IE7. Following your the reading you point me too, which was kind of against using those filter, I thought I'd go around the issue and used the opacity and filter for IE in the CSS using a different div for my background and my content to avoid inheritance of the opacity.  Well... I came accross the same issue! I'll let you know when I find the proper solution...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should try the CSS3 as well as other vendor prefixes for gradient and opacity to be sure it's consistent.

Secondly, try not setting the negative margins for the image and instead setting a hidden overflow for the parent div. That is to say:

`#bottompub
{
    overflow:hidden;
}`

EDIT:
This works on IE9:

```
/* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#FF0000FF,endColorstr=#FFFFFFFF);
/* For Internet Explorer 8+ */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#FF0000FF,endColorstr=#FFFFFFFF)";
```

Also, take a look at this for all the vendor prefixes, it's a short and good read:
http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: Thanks. I got rid of the negative margin and made it work without the filter. Again, as soon as I turn on the filter, it is cropped.  I don't get why you said a overflow hidden though, I used a visible to make it work. I must say that I don't know other vendor prefixes for gradient...

Comment: Hi, the overflow thing was to not show the image that was larger than its container, so you wouldn't have to use negative margins for positioning.

Comment: In your filter, the HEX colour code is wrong: `#B289BAE4` has to many characters. This could be the problem.

Comment: @Francisc, that's not wrong, it's the MS notation to get transparency, the first two digits are a hex conversion of the transparency value you need : see [this link for more](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/)

Comment: I see, didn't know that but still strange. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Indeed, it was for the transparency! Thanks for your input!

Comment: I've edited my answer by the way, and the code above works on IE9 both locally and on a test server I used.